# How to adapt Matlab's polyfit and array indexing into c?

Tags: c, matlab, linear-regression

I'm trying to convert this line of Matlab code into c programming language:

```
coefs = polyfit(X(50:(length(X)-50)),Y(50:(length(Y)-50)),1);
```

I've tried different implementations, but none of them seem to give me the same `coefs(1)` value, i.e, slope. All I'm interested in is in the slope.

*Note: all the code is probably over-complicated. As of know, I don't know any better. Still new to this.*

<s>Since c doesn't have dynamic arrays, I have two linked lists, X and Y</s>

**UPDATE:** I changed everything to `*float` instead of lists. Below is the functions' code and the declarations.

```
float getSumF(float * head, int size){
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        sum = sum + head[i];
    }
    return sum;
}


float coef (float* xx, float* yy, int size) {
    int i=0;
    float sumX2 = 0;
    float sumXY = 0;
    float sumX = 0;
    float sumY = 0;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        sumX = sumX + xx[i];
        sumY = sumY + yy[i];
        sumX2 = sumX2 + xx[i]*xx[i];
        sumXY = sumXY + xx[i]*yy[i];
    }
    float slope = (size*sumXY-sumX*sumY)/(size*sumX2-sumX*sumX);
    return slope;
}

int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    int threshold=20;
    int k, i, j;
    float slope, angle;
    int width, height, channels;
    float* X = 0;
    float* Y = 0;
    int arraysizeX = 0;
    float* osc = 0;
    int arraysizeOsc = 0;
    float* coord = 0;
    int arraysizeCoord = 0;
    unsigned char *img;
```

The way I achieve the array indexing of Matlab is through this:

```
for(i=0;i<1440;i++){
    if (coord[i] > 0){
        X = realloc (X,++arraysizeX*sizeof(*X));
        Y = realloc (Y,arraysizeX*sizeof(*Y));
        X[arraysizeX-1]=i+1;
        Y[arraysizeX-1]=coord[i];
    }
}
if (arraysizeX>102){
    slope=coef(X+50,Y+50,arraysizeX-100);
}
else{
    if(arraysizeX==0){
        free(X);
        free(Y);
        free(coord);
        printf("Threshold too low. Exiting.\n");
        return 3;
    }
    slope = coef(X,Y,arraysizeX);
}
```

I also coded the same linear regression algorithm to matlab, here:

```
sizeX=length(X);
sumX2 = 0;
sumXY = 0;
for i=1:sizeX
    sumX2 = sumX2 + X(i)*X(i);
    sumXY = sumXY + X(i)*Y(i);
endfor
slope=(sizeX*sumXY-sum(X)*sum(Y))/(sizeX*sumX2-sum(X)*sum(X));
```

`slope_polyfit = 7.4615e-3`
`slope_matlab = 5.8421e-3`
`slope_c = -0.175331`

Now.. is my mistake in the `coef` call/function? Have I done everything right?

**UPDATE:** The solution I provided (with guidance from the comments) is functioning properly. The error was in the matlab code, in the obtention of `X` and `Y` arrays.

Comment: C **does** have a form of dynamic arrays with a help of `realloc` function.

Comment: Btw.. replace `X = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));` with `X = malloc(sizeof *X);`. It is both shorter and more robust.

Comment: @tstanisl It could maybe simplify the code, and make `push` useless, but I'm not sure how it would help my problem exactly. And malloc edit done, ty

Comment: ```list_t * X = NULL;
    list_t * Y = NULL;
    X->next=NULL;
    X->val=-1
``` ---> 1) This seems wrong. And why not just call `malloc()` instantly? 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc()`. 3) Why do you ignore it's return value outside of `main()`?

Comment: Rather than playing with a spectacularly inefficient linked list, use a flat array. `float *X = calloc(N, sizeof *X);`. If N is not known in advance do: `float *X = NULL; int N = 0;`. The array can be enlarged with `X = realloc(X, ++N * sizeof *X);`. Consider adding error handling.

Comment: ```for (i=0;i<50;i++){
        pointerX=pointerX->next;
        pointerY=pointerY->next;
    }``` ---> This doesn't seem to be doing anything meaningful.

Comment: @Haris I'm too dumb to understand what you just said. So, you want me to remove (list_t*) from every malloc call AND do list_t * X = malloc ( size of *X) instead of what I was doing? The question number 3 i just flat out didn't comprehend. For your other question, that cycle is just getting the pointer for the 50th element. But You're telling me it's useles so... I could do pointerX=X+50 couldn't I?

Comment: @tstanisl I LOL'd at "spectacularly inefficient linked list". I know right? I'm just great at C atm. I can make the changes to turn my lists into that calloc/realloc. But I'd still have to run/call everything through pointers. I'd guess that my code sucks because I'm too rudimentary in handling pointers, to say the least. But although it sucks, it should give me the same slope value

Comment: If normal arrays were used rather than crappy linked lists then `slope` function could be refactored to `float coef(size_t n, float xx[static n], float yy[static n])` and the slope coefficient could be computed in a single simple loop.

Comment: 1) Yes, I meant exactly that. 2) No, the loop doesn't seem to be getting the 50th pointer. The only thing changing is the value of `i`.

Comment: @Haris So, I should add `pointerX->val=pointerX->next->val` before the `pointerX=pointerX->next` ? Or does `pointerX=X+50` immediately places pointerX looking at X's 50th value?

Comment: @tstanisl I'm trying your flat array implementation in another program. Let me se if I got this straight: basically, I should create a `float` array, by making `float*X=(float*)calloc()` of `N` elements with `float` size. Whenever I want to increase one element, I `realloc()` with an increased `N`. To access each element, I use the pointer `X` and the index `[i]` i.e. `X[i]`. Is that it?

Comment: Almost. Firstly, don't do this idiotic cast from `void*`. It's ugly and it actually makes code **less** typesafe. Secondly, you can start with `float *X=0; int N = 0;`. The realloc is fine with `NULL` pointer. It will work like `malloc()` in such a case. The `calloc`/`malloc` is useful for optimization when you know the size of array in advance. As you said, use `X[i]` for indexing. Remember to do `free(X)` at the end to avoid memory-leak.

Comment: @tstanisl So, this:  `int N = 0; float *X=0; X= calloc(N, sizeof(float));` ? But what exactly does this allocate, if N=0? It seems to me that is not allocating anything, and that in order to add any element whatsoever (including the first), I have to `realloc (X,++N*sizeof(float));`. And then afterwards `X[N-1]` = whatever I want

Comment: No. You can use `realloc` all the time because `realloc(NULL, 3 * sizeof(float))` works exactly the same as `malloc(3 * sizeof(float))`. This feature is not widely communicated so people use this brain-dead `malloc + realloc` pattern all the time.

Comment: @tstanisl what exactly are you answering "no" to? I'm feeling I'm getting as brain-dead as `malloc+realloc`, lol. You're telling me that `X=calloc(0, sizeof(float));` allocates memory to store 1 element through `X[0]` ?

Comment: No. The `calloc(0, sizeof(float));` does not allocate anything. It returns a cookie (potentially `NULL`) that is only suitable for `free()` or `realloc()`. Nothing else. Don't use `X=calloc(0,...)` / `X=malloc(0)` thing. Use `X=0`/`X=NULL` directly.

Comment: @tstanisl Then I just have to make `float*X=0; X=realloc(1,sizeof(float));` and then insert first item by `X[0]=element` ?

Comment: You start with `int N = 0; float*X=0;`. To add a new element at the end you do: `X=realloc(X,++N * sizeof *X); X[N-1] = 42; `

Comment: @tstanisl thanks. And at the end I just have to free the pointer X i.e. `free(X)`, right? No need to free one node/element at a time, like I used to do with a linked list, right?

Comment: Yes. Simple `free(X)` will suffice. It will work even if `X` is `0`.

Comment: @tstanisl Great. The other smaller program worked with `float*`. Thanks! So I'm heading back to the bigger one. Now, would this work `slope=coef(X+50, Y+50,arraysizeX-100);` ? Being `X` and `Y` both `float*` and the last argument is the number of loops I want the function to perform. This approach to mimic the `polyfit(X(50:(length(X)-50)),Y(50:(length(Y)-50)),1);`

Comment: @tstanisl after replacing the 4 lists I had with `float*`, and deleting all the list handling functions, my code is now half the size. This is great. Although, I still can't calculate the slope properly / have the same value as I have in Matlab.

Comment: can you show some numbers and some code? Is the difference significant?

Comment: @tstanisl I'm gonna try to save both `X` and `Y`, from matlab and C to a `.csv`. Then compare both, to see if the problem is the linear regression/polyfit or if it's a problem in arrays. I'll get back to you if I reach a conclusion

Comment: @tstanisl I didn't succeed in writing to .csv. But I coded the same linear regression algorithm to Matlab, and got `slope_matlab =  5.8421e-3`. While `slope_polyfit = 7.4615e-3`. And way off `slope_c = 0.452119`. Something ain't right. Gonna paste the float* handling functions to get the slope in the post. And the matlab one

Comment: Try replacing `int sum=0;` with `float sum = 0;` in `getSumF`. Moreover `getSumF` should return `float`

Comment: @tstanisl it does make a difference. `slope_c` went from `0.452119` to `-0.175331`

Comment: the matlab code does not update `sumXY`. It stays `0` there

Comment: btw.. there is no need for `getSumF`. Just compute `sumX` and `sumY` in a loop in  `coef()`

Comment: @tstanisl it was updating, but I must have deleted that line while pasting in stackoverflow. And you're also right about `getSumF`, it was an updated remain of the `list` implementation. Changed it and updated the post. `slope` result didn't change tho. If you're not seeing anything else, I must be messing up the creation of `coord` array, that originates `X` and `Y`

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks for your help. With your correction of float getSumF, I reached the right answer. The problem was, the matlab code I was provided had an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As updated in the post: the function `getSumF` should be `float`, and so should be the `sum` variable. Other than that, my implementation was in fact working. Another adjustment to improve efficiency was changing everything from linked-lists to `float*`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).